# How to read the value from the html response body in JMeter

Tags: jmeter-5.0

The response body is in the html format. I want to read the value of code from the JMeter response body and assign to a string variable.

```
  <a style="word-break: break-all; color: #2f2f2f; font-size: 14px" target="_blank"
href="https://mytest.app.net/#/registration?mysite=9818ffa2-52c0-15ec-ae45-02b72c6380ad&amp;code=1207a949-8453-4cs9-b360-26032bddb845&amp;locale=en_US">
https://mytest.app.net/#/registration?mysite=9818ffa2-52c0-15ec-ae45-02b72c6380ad&amp;code=1207a949-8453-4cs9-b360-26032bddb845&amp;locale=en_US"
                            </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regular Expression Extractor** of JMeter for parsing html and then assign parsed value to reference name.